# How to use BCM2045 Bluetooth USB Dongle?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bluetooth

I'm trying to use it with Windows 10 but it's giving me an error when I plug it in:

[image]

The only driver I can find is only compatible with Vista:

https://download.cnet.com/Network-Broadcom-Broadcom-BCM2045-Driver-Version-A00/3000-2108_4-177233.html

Comment: Have you tried the Windows 7 driver from https://oemdrivers.com/bluetooth-broadcom-bcm2045?

Comment: @DavidPostill Doesn't work. I guess I'll need to buy a newer one with compatibility.

Comment: Have you tried installing a driver for a *different* Broadcom USB dongle?  Linux has a single unified Broadcom bluetooth driver, which suggests that the Broadcom devices might be similar enough for a newer driver to support an older device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am very sure you are out of luck and will have to replace the Dongle with a newer device.

[Bluetooth](https://oemdrivers.com/bluetooth-broadcom-bcm2045)

> The Broadcom BCM2045 is a monolithic, single-chip, stand-alone
> baseband processor with an integrated 2.4-GHz transceiver for
> Bluetooth 2.0 + EDR applications. It is backward-compatible with
> Bluetooth 1.1 or 1.2-based systems. Usually used on USB Dongles or
> PCI- Express cards on laptops from the 2010's.

This is an old design and does not have Windows 8 or 10 drivers  available.

If Windows 10 cannot find its own drivers, there is not much you can do.